# How to maintain the existing background color of h3 element when hover on selected item

Tags: css, background, css-selectors, hover

I have an accordion like control in which an item will be expanded and another will be collapsed. I have a common background color (which differs for various themes ) and a different hover color for all headers.

I need to maintain the background color for active item which is expanded and hover color need not to be applied for this item alone.

I have a class to identify this and I apply a certain background through hover selector

**CSS**

```
.e-active:hover {
  background: #f00;      
}
```

I tried with transparent and none but it changes the background to white

This is hard coded CSS but I need a generic CSS such that the existing background color will be maintained for active h3 element on hover state for any theme

Comment: Are you able to see your css in browser developer tools?

Comment: Yes, css is applied but I don't want to apply a specific background color directly. I need to inherit the same existing background. I tried "initial" and "inherit" too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:not` css selector

```css
div {
  background: green;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

h3 {
  background: blue;
  padding: 6px;
}

h3:not(.e-active):hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="e-active">Heading 1</h3>
  <h3>Heading 2</h3>
  <h3>Heading 3</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need to include some form of JavaScript/jQuery to implement this dynamically (although I am certain you could use SASS/SCSS to achieve this dynamically as well).

The main focus of the script would be to check if the heading has the `.e-active` and not apply the `.hover` class in that instance. Once that's down, you can simply change `:hover` to `.hover`.

Here is an example - run the code snippet to see it work:

```js
$('h1').mouseenter(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('e-active')) { //if heading does NOT have e-active class, apply hover effect
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }
});
$('h1').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
h1 {
  background-color: salmon;
}
h1.hover {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Non active Heading 1</h1>
<h1 class="e-active">Active Heading 2</h1>
<h1>Non active Heading 3</h1>
```

---

## EDIT:

[Bhuwans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57266445/6049581) that shows the use of the `:not` selector is a much cleaner way of achieving that - I would suggest using that route first whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I need to apply a generic CSS as background so that existing will be maintained and I need not speicfy the color directly.

Comment: Oh I see, you're probably going to have to involve some jQuery/JavaScript then to achieve it. The easiest way would be to just add a class change on hover instead, I'll write an example for you to use if no one else comes back with a pure CSS solution :)

Comment: @keerthana - Have a look at [Bhuwans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57266445/6049581) above mine - the `:not` pseudo-selector is probably the best way to go about this - if it works for you, please mark his answer as "_accepted_" - (it's the big tick under the voting buttons)